# Xpages Null or empty string

Tags: components, xpages

I am working with xpages components and it is hard for me to quess when the getComponent("comp").getValue() returns null or when returns "" (empty string).

Is there a way to tell? Are there components which return null when other components return ""?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A component will have a null value if the value property has not been assigned. That can happen if the it's bound to a field on a document and that document does not yet have the field, e.g. it's a brand new document. It can also happen if it's bound to a scoped variable that hasn't been set yet.

It's best practice to bind, wherever possible, to the data source rather than go via the component. This way `document1.getItemValueString("myField")` will return a blank string if myField hasn't been set on document1, as well as if myField's value is "". Also, if in the future youo delete the component `comp`, the compiler won't (and can't) tell you you're calling that component in SSJS and you'll get a runtime error. If you're using document1.getItemValueString("myField"), it will still work.

Plus, as Tim Tripcony said, it's slower https://twitter.com/timtripcony/status/359532216382001152 and this blog post goes into much greater depth on why to talk to data not components http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-942UPQ

Comment: I second Paul: talk to data